# Trying to understand NSDatePicker

Tags: macos, datepicker, julian-date, nsdatepicker

I'm desperately trying to understand swift's DatePicker. I have a need to select dates from Julian Day 0 (11/24/4714 BCE) to dates in the future. When I extract the DateComponents from the DatePicker, they do not appear to be a 'proleptic' gregorian calendar. For instance, by selecting 3/1/300 AD (or CE), the month and day are 2/29. This seems consistent with the Julian Calendar, a date I cannot select with the DatePicker's calendar set to iso8601 or gregorian. I am familiar with the date of adoption of the Gregorian calendar, and indeed this is where the discrepancies begin. But why won't it calculate the proleptic dates, or am I misunderstanding this. Extracting these components is necessary for calculating various quantities such as Julian Day or converting from one calendar to another. Even a suggestion of where to find the info would be appreciated.

---Edited to show code -----

```
@IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {
    var mycal = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    //var mycal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let picked_date:Date = datePicker.dateValue
    let formatter1 = DateFormatter()
    formatter1.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
    let picked_format = formatter1.string(from: picked_date)
    //print("picked_format: \(picked_format)")
    let format_date = formatter1.date(from: picked_format)
    var tz: String { return TimeZone.current.identifier }
    let myzone = UTC.state == NSOnState ? tz : "GMT"
    //let era = AD.state == NSOnState ? 1 : 0
    mycal.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: myzone)!
    var comps = mycal.dateComponents([.year,
                                    .month,
                                    .day,
                                    .hour,
                                    .minute,
                                    .second,
                                    //.era,
                                    //.nanosecond,
                                    .timeZone],
                                from: format_date!)
    print(comps.month!)
    print(comps.day!)
```

Comment: 1) This has nothing to do with swift.
2) Have you read the documentation? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIDatePicker

Comment: Yes, I have read the docs, at least the ones I could find. I understand that 10 days are 'removed' from the Gregorian Calendar. This leads me to believe that you either cannot select dates from 10/6/1582 -10/14/1582 (which appears NOT to be the case) or the calendar would simply continue backwards from Oct 15, 1582 using the same Gregorian calendar rules we are all accustomed to. This also seems to NOT be the case. And yes, I suppose in retrospect, it is more of a Cocoa thing: I'm using the MacOS datepicker, not the iOS one, though I suspect they behave similarly.

Comment: Thanks, Maddy, for the edits of tags and title.

Comment: `NSDatePicker` doesn't calculate days and you can't extract DateComponents from a date picker. What is the calendar of the date picker and which calendar do you use to extract the date components?

Comment: Info: [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html)

Comment: I use the .iso8601 calendar for the date picker. I use dateFormatter  and then extract the dateComponents from the formatted date. It works fine for any date after adoption of the gregorian calendar. I don't quite understand your comment: "NSDatePicker doesn't calculate days ...". I just want to extract the selected date from date picker, then use those quantities programatically.

Comment: I've pored over the Date and Time Programming Guide. I must be missing (or misunderstanding) something. Despite it being in Objective-C (I'm using Swift and tried to 'skip' Obj-C), it basically makes sense. But I still don't understand when I choose a date in DatePicker and extract the DateComponents (via DateFormatter), the dates are different than those that I selected. If it's truly a "proleptic" Gregorian Calendar, it should keep the dates the same.

Comment: Sorry, typo, should be "NSDatePicker doesn't calculate dates". Can you show us your code?

Comment: Edited to show the code. In Xcode 8, a datepicker created in the storyboard connected to this code will show a "comps.month" of 2 and a "comps.day" of 29 when 3/10/1500 is selected as the date.

Comment: Why do you use a formatter instead of getting the date components from `picked_date`? Is the calendar of the date picker iso8601? Are all locales the same?

Comment: Edited again to show locale. I added the locale specifier yesterday after watching two hour long videos from the Apple WWDC about calendar calculations. Unfortunately, no change in results. I had been extracting the dateComponents directly from the date object but read that directly using date objects was not a best practice. Indeed, when I did that, the time would suddenly be off by 11 minutes 56 seconds ... a problem that disappeared after using DateFormatter as the go-between. BTW, I tried the code with DateComponents extracting directly from 'picked_date' anyway ... same results.

Comment: Another curiosity: If I uncomment the print statement for the picked_format, the date appears correctly! For 3/1/1500, the formatted picked_date is "1500-03-01T12:00:00-07:48:04". This is the correct date (though the time is off; 12:00 is selected in DatePicker)! But printing the DateComponents still shows month "2" and day "20". I really hope this will spark someone's ideas, because I'm confounded!

Comment: I added code to specify the datePicker's calendar. Previously, I did NOT specify this ... I believe that means it defaults to my locale, which would set it go ".gregorian". Specifying ".iso8601" (consistent with my dateFormatter) appears to correct my date discrepancy. Setting BOTH to .gregorian also produces correct results in the DateComponents. Guys ... I'm a noob. I don't want to post this as an answer yet without some input from all of you who have been so helpful ... opinions?

Comment: Oh, and my apologies. As you might surmise, I specified the calendar for the DateComponents and the DateFormatter in my previous code, but neglected to specify the calendar for the DatePicker ... that was careless, and I mistakenly said in a previous comment that I HAD specified .iso8601 for the DatePicker.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line: The discrepancies in what was shown in DatePicker vs the 'elements' of the date object it produced (namely, YEAR, MONTH and DAY) were due wholly to a careless mistake I made writing the code: The failure to ensure that all the objects that dealt with dates were specified to the same Calendar. Initially, my DateFormatter and DateComponents objects were set to ".iso8601" and failing to specify a calendar for the DatePicker defaulted it to my locale, which meant ".gregorian". This produced a 10 day discrepancy in the date prior to Oct 15, 1582. Also: A DatePicker using the Gregorian calendar will allow you to select days from 5 Oct 1582 - 14 Oct 1582 (inclusive), just as I would expect from a proleptic calendar. A DatePicker using the ISO calendar will NOT allow dates in this range. Stepping down from 15 Oct 1582 by one day will result in the DatePicker showing 4 Oct 1582 ... not the result I would expect if it is based on the proleptic Gregorian.

Some caveats, though. Apple's documentation and the ISO standard itself lead me to believe that the ISO calendar was based on a proleptic Gregorian calendar. This proved to be untrue. You can repeat for yourself the following: Create a DatePicker specifying the ISO calendar and it will allow you to choose dates which do not exist in the Gregorian calendar, namely leap years for such years as 1500, 1400, 1300, 1100, 1000, etc. This is more in keeping with the ISO calendar behaving like the Julian Calendar prior to the adoption date. Indeed, the date discrepancies begin to narrow as the year number decreases because the ISO calendar is counting those years as leap years. The error becomes ZERO  from 1 March 200 - 28 Feb 300 AD, exactly as one would expect of a Julian Calendar vs a proleptic Gregorian calendar. I don't know if I am misunderstanding how the ISO calendar is supposed to behave, or if this is a bug. Thanks to Willeke for leading me to the correct solution!